# Use SqlCipher on Visual Studio

Tags: encryption, console-application, sqlcipher

I´ve already compiled SQLCipher for windows and encrypt/decrypt a database file using SQLCipher at command line.
 The problem is at the last part of [this tutorial](http://www.jerryrw.com/howtocompile.php) when I use SQLCipher in Visual Studio.
It looks like the application skips this code line, because it is not encrypting neither decrypting, i'm not getting any error.

```
if (sqlite3_exec(db, (const char*)"PRAGMA key ='password'", NULL, NULL, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
            printf("Accepted Key\n");
        };
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong? or provide some sample C code?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of items to address here.  First, checking for `SQLITE_OK` as a status code from `sqlite3_exec` does not mean that the provided password is valid for the database.  In order to validate that, once the database has been keyed, we recommend you perform a query such as:

`SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master;`

This table will always be present, regardless of the state of your application schema.

Next, to verify that you have properly integrated the SQLCipher library within your application, we can query the database for the `PRAGMA cipher_version;` reported by the library.  Below is a sample for doing so:

```
int rc;
sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

rc = sqlite3_open(":memory:", &db);
if(rc != SQLITE_OK){
  printf("failed to open database\n");
}
rc = sqlite3_prepare(db, "PRAGMA cipher_version;", -1, &stmt, NULL);
rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
if(rc == SQLITE_ROW){
  printf("SQLCipher version:%s\n", sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0));
}
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
if(db != NULL){
  sqlite3_close(db);
}
```